What's causing this discoloration in my clutch line?
This is my Ducati Monster 696 2012. The clutch line is discolored as you can see. I have been less than diligent in flushing my clutch fluid, so I would guess the fluid absorbed water and caused rust. I know the bike is advertised as having "steel braided cables" but I'm actually unaware of how they're configured and how to correct this.
Is the steel braided cable inside of the tubing to add rigidity, and the fluid has rust particles in it, so a couple flushes should clear it out? OR are there basically a tube within the braided line through which the fluid flows, and the seal is compromised and fluid is leaking and corroding the steel cables so the whole assembly needs to be replaced? There is a similar discoloration near the master cylinder.
(Nevermind the broken trickle charger plug, I have a replacement for that)


I don't know what the braided portion which is on the outside, but whatever it's made out of it's just a covering so as to protect and support the actual part which does the work. This is an "inner" tube (no, not the tire kind, lol) which runs the length. This tube is usually made out of teflon or some kind of tubing which will hold the hydraulic fluid.
As for the braided part, I'd suggest it is nothing more than dirt/grime. The tube of the hose (inside part) will not leak/purge fluid unless there's a big problem (burst or breaks). I would bet if you put some dishwashing liquid cut with water on it, then use some elbow grease, it'd probably clean up. If not, you can always replace it if it is that much of an eyesore to you. As long as you don't see any drippage or the master reservoir isn't getting lower, there's really no worry about the line itself having an issue.
